# I want to group the columns of the matrix A which have the same value for the third line in Matlab

Tags: matlab

For a matrix A (4 rows, 1000 columns). I want to group the columns of the matrix A which have the same value for the third line. so I must have sub matrix with a third row that contains the same value.

for example:

if:

```
A =

     1     4     5     2     2     2     2     1     1     5
     1     4     5     4     4     2     2     4     5     2
     3     3     3     3     4     1     3     5     3     4
     4     5     5     5     4     1     5     5     5     5
```

then

```
A1 =

     1     4     5     2     2     1
     1     4     5     4     2     5
     3     3     3     3     3     3
     4     5     5     5     5     5

A2 =

     2     5
     4     2
     4     4
     4     5

A3 =

     2
     2
     1
     1
```

the result can be in the form of a cell.

Comment: Take a look at [`sortrows()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/sortrows.html).  It won't do exactly what you want, but it will get you part of the way there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the assignment in a single line using [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html):

```
A = [1     4     5     2     2     2     2     1     1     5;
     1     4     5     4     4     2     2     4     5     2;
     3     3     3     3     4     1     3     5     3     4;
     4     5     5     5     4     1     5     5     5     5
     ];

out = accumarray(A(3,:)', (1:size(A,2)), [], @(x){A(:,x)} );
```

With this, `out{i}` contains all columns of `A` where the third row of `A` equals `i` (and empty in case there is no valid column).

If you want `out{i}` to contain columns corresponding to the i-th smallest unique value in the third row of `A`, you can use [GRP2IDX](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/grp2idx.html) from the statistics toolbox first:

```
[idx,correspondingEntryInA] = grp2idx(A(3,:)'); %'#
out = accumarray(idx, (1:size(A,2)), [], @(x){A(:,x)} );
```

Here, `out{i}` contains the columns corresponding to `correspondingEntryInA(i)`.

Answer (score 4):

here's one possible hack (warning: I haven't been able to check this):

```
A =

 1     4     5     2     2     2     2     1     1     5
 1     4     5     4     4     2     2     4     5     2
 3     3     3     3     4     1     3     5     3     4
 4     5     5     5     4     1     5     5     5     5

specialRow=3;
unqCols = unique(A(specialRow,:));
numUnq = length(unqCols);
sepMats{numUnq}=[];

for i=1:numUnq
    sepMats{i} = A(:,A(specialRow,:)==unqCols(i));
end
```

Answer (score 3):

In the example you shown, there are 4 unique elements in the 3rd row, so you should obtain 4 submatrices, but you only show 3 ?

Here is one way:

```
clear all;

%data
A = [1     4     5     2     2     2     2     1     1     5;
     1     4     5     4     4     2     2     4     5     2;
     3     3     3     3     4     1     3     5     3     4;
     4     5     5     5     4     1     5     5     5     5
     ]

%engine
row = 3;
b   = unique(A(row,:));
r   = arrayfun(@(i) A(:,A(row,:)==b(i)),1:length(b), 'UniformOutput',false);

r{:}
```